# How apache runs PHP for pages

Tags: php, apache

Imagine there is a PHP page on `http://server/page.php`.

Client(s) send 100 requests from browser to the server for that page simultaneously.

Does the server run 100 separate processes of `php.exe` simultaneously?

Does it re-interpret the `page.php` 100 times?

Comment: Although this is a good question but 1 it seems like off topic for SO and second there doesn't appear to be some existing research, as Google is filled with results for this question

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer is highly variable, according to server config.

Let's answer question 1 first:

> Does the server run 100 separate processes of php.exe simultaneously?

This depends on the way PHP is installed. If PHP is being run via CGI, then the answer is "Yes, each request calls a separate instance of PHP". If it's being run via an Apache module, then the answer is "No, each request starts a new PHP thread within the Apache executable".

Similar variations will exist for other web servers. Please note that for a Unix/Linux based operating system, running separate copies of the executable for each request is not necessarily a bad thing for performance; the core of the OS is designed such that in many cases, tasks are better done by a number of separate executables rather than one monolithic one.

However, no matter what you do about it, having large numbers of simultaneous requests will drain your server resources and lead to timeouts and errors for your users. This is why it is important for your PHP programs to finish running as quickly as possible. Do not write PHP programs for web consumption that are slow to run; if you're likely to have a lot of traffic, you need to test for performance as much as you do for functionality. Having your programs exit quickly will dramatically reduce the likelihood of having a significant number of simultaneous requests, which will obviously have a big impact on your site's performance.

Now your second question:

> Does it re-interpret the page.php 100 times?

For a standard PHP installation, the answer here is "Yes it does, and yes it does have a performance impact."

However, PHP provides several Caching solutions that are designed specifically to mitigate this. The main options are APC and the Zend Cache, either of which can be installed as standard modules. Using these modules will mean that PHP caches the interpreted code, so it can be run much faster for subsequent calls.

The Zend Cache will be included as part of the standard PHP installation as of the forthcoming PHP 5.5 release.

Comment: Great answer, +1. However, I thought PHP was going to include APC, not Zend Cache?

Comment: @halfer - no, the went with Zend. They've renamed it to just `OpCache` (ie without the Zend name), but it is the Zend cache. Zend open sourced it last year specifically in order to get it into 5.5.

Comment: Ah right, Wikipedia is out of date on this one, as am I! Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Apache2 has multiple different mode to work.

In "prefork" (the most commonly used) mode, Apache will create process for every request, each process will run a own php.exe. Config file will assign a maximum number of connections (`MaxClients` in httpd.conf), Apache will only create MaxClients. This is to prevent memory exhaustion. More requests are queued, waiting for the previous request to complete.

If you do not install opcode cache extensions like APC, XCache, eAccelerator, php.exe will re-interpret the page.php 100 times.

Comment: Your English is great!

Answer (score 2):

It depends.

There are different ways of setting things up, and things can get quite complex.

The short answer is 'more or less'. A number of apache processes will be spawned, the PHP code will be parsed and run.

If you want to avoid the parsing overhead use an opcode cache. [APC](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php) (Alternative PHP Cache) is a very popular one. This has a number of neat features which are worth digging into, but without any config other than installing it it will ensure that each php page is only parsed into opcode once.

To change how many apache services are spawned, most likely you'll be using [MPM Prefork](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/prefork.html). This lets you decide if how you want Apache to deal with multiple users.

For general advice, in my experience (small sites, not a huge amount of traffic), installing APC is worth doing, for everything else the defaults are not too bad.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of answers to this. In general, Apache will create a process for an incoming request, so it is possible that 100 process are created. However, a process takes time to create, so it might be that by the time a process has finished and died, one of those 100 connections comes in a fraction of a second later (since 100 connections at *exactly* the same time is very rare indeed, unless you're Google).

However, let us imagine that 100 processes do really need to be held in memory simultaneously, but that there is only room for 50 in available server RAM. In that case, 50 connections will be served, and 50 will have to wait for processes to die and be re-spawned. Thus, a random half of those requests will be delayed, though if a process create-process-die sequence only takes a fraction of a second, they won't have to wait very long. This is why, when improving server capacity, reducing your page load time is as important as adding more RAM - the sooner a process finishes, the sooner a new one can take its place.

One way, incidentally, to reduce load time is to spawn a number of PHP processes and hold them in memory. This is the basis of FastCGI (or fcgid, which is compatible). Rather than creating and killing a process for every request, a process is spawned in memory immediately and is re-used for several requests. For PHP, these are usually configure to die after a certain number of page requests (e.g. 1000) as historically PHP has had quite a lot of memory leaks (the more a process is reused, the worse the memory leaks get).

You ask if a page is re-interpreted for every request. Normally yes, but if you also run a PHP Accelerator, then no - the byte-code that PHP compiles to is cached and reused. Thus, mixing the FastCGI approach with an accelerator can make for a very speedy server indeed. Standard PHP does not come with an accelerator, but Zend Cache is [scheduled for inclusion into the PHP core](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/optimizerplus).